# is the diagonalization of a matrix a linear transformation?if yes, then how

Tags: transformation, diagonalization

How diagonalization of a matrix can be called as a linear transformation? Since multiplying a matrix A by P(inv)AP is not a linear operation

Answer (score 1):

A=(-7,2;-15,4) is diagonalizable to (1,0;0,2). If we add (1,0;0,0) the resulting matrix is not diagonalizable in RxR.